Reactor with mixing and a cooling jacket
Suppose we have a reactor with mixing that contains a known quantity of water at $121^{\circ}C$ (due to the pressure, the water is liquid). We want to cool the water to $37^{\circ} C$ by using cooling water that has an initial temeperature of $10^{\circ} C$ and that circulates through the cooling jacket.
I calculated the heat transfer area $A_{\text{transfer}}$ and based on the recommendations in the literature I considered the global heat transfer coefficient to be $1100 \text{W}/\text{m}^2\text{K}$. I would like to write the heat balance sheet by considering the flow rate as known and I would like to find the final temperature of the cooling water from the jacket, but I don't know how to handle the fact that in the formula for $Q_{\text{lost}}$ I have $mC_{p}\Delta T$ and in the formula for $Q_{\text{given}}$ I have $G_vC_p\Delta T$.
Would it be a better idea to consider the final temperature as known and to find the cooling agent's flow rate?

Should that be kg$\cdot$K rather than kelvin-gram-kelvin?

What is $G_v$? I think you trying to mix 2 things: steady state and transient. If the fluid in reactor does not flow in or out and you are trying to cool it down by a fluid stream, then the temperature of reactor fluid will get exponentially close to cooling fluid temperature over time. So the question might be, how fast do you want to cool the reactor.

Should come down to power in = power out. Allow to vary those values that can change like area, cooling flow rate, acceptable max T... And with heat exchangers you won't get a precise answer as there are factors in reality not included in the books...

@TomášLétal $G_v$ is the flow rate of the cooling water that circulates through the cooling jacket. The liquid in the reactor stays in the reactor. Can the final temperature of the cooling water in the cooling jacket be greater than the desired final temperature of the liquid in the reactor (i.e., $37^{\circ}\text{C}$)? Using $K=1100 \text{W}/\text{m}^2\text{K},$ I computed the time for cooling to be somewhere around $1300 \text{s}$.

@Transistor thank you, it should have been $\text{W}/\text{m}^2\text{K}$. I edited my post now.

The reactor fluid with mass $m_r$ and thermal capacity $c_{pr}$ will experience temperature $T_r$ change in time $t$, which will depend on the heat flux into cooling fluid $\dot{Q}_c$:
$$-m_r\cdot c_{pr}\cdot \frac{dT_r}{dt} = \dot{Q}_c(t)$$
The heat flux from reactor fluid into cooling fluid also depends on temperature difference between the fluids, where both fluid temperatures change over time, but for simplicity, lets suppose the mean cooling fluid temperature $\overline{T}_{c}$ is constant and that reactor fluid is ideally mixed (uniform temperature):
$$\dot{Q}_c = K\cdot A\cdot \left(T_{r}(t)-\overline{T}_{c}\right)$$
Combining the equations leads to a differential equation:
$$-m_r\cdot c_{pr}\cdot \frac{dT_r}{dt} = K\cdot A\cdot \left(T_{r}(t)-\overline{T}_{c}\right)$$
This can be solved by separating variables and integrating both sides:
$$-\frac{m_r\cdot c_{pr}}{K\cdot A}\cdot\int\limits_{T_{rs}}^{T_{rf}} \frac{dT_r}{T_{r}(t)-\overline{T}_{c}} = \int\limits_{0}^{t_f} dt = t_f$$
Focusing only on fluid temperature difference in time:
$$T_{rc}(t) = T_{r}(t)-\overline{T}_{c}$$
This changes the left side a bit:
$$-\frac{m_r\cdot c_{pr}}{K\cdot A}\cdot\int\limits_{T_{rs}-\overline{T}_{c}}^{T_{rf}-\overline{T}_{c}} \frac{1}{T_{rc}} dT_{rc} = t_f$$
Left side can be integrated:
$$\ln\left(\frac{T_{rf}-\overline{T}_{c}}{T_{rs}-\overline{T}_{c}}\right) = -\frac{K\cdot A}{m_r\cdot c_{pr}}\cdot t_f$$
Exponentiation of both sides:
$$\frac{T_{rf}-\overline{T}_{c}}{T_{rs}-\overline{T}_{c}} = \exp\left(-\frac{K\cdot A}{m_r\cdot c_{pr}}\cdot t_f\right)$$
Finally, the reactor fluid temperature as a function of time is:
$$T_{rf}(t_f) = \overline{T}_{c} + \left(T_{rs}-\overline{T}_{c}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{K\cdot A}{m_r\cdot c_{pr}}\cdot t_f\right)$$
From practical point of view, you can directly use these equations to calculate minimum required overall heat transfer coefficient $K_\text{min}$ when you assume theoretical best case scenario where $\overline{T}_c = T_{ci}$:
$$K_\text{min} = -\frac{m_r\cdot c_{pr}}{t_f\cdot A}\cdot \ln\left(\frac{T_{rf}-T_{ci}}{T_{rs}-T_{ci}}\right)$$
And since this coefficient also depends on cooling fluid flow rate $\dot{m}_c$, you could use it to calculate theoretical minimum cooling fluid flow rate $\dot{m}_{c,\text{min}}$ (probably using some iterative method, since the relationship is nonlinear).

Calculating cooling fluid outlet temperature is more difficult, but you could use the amount of heat that is removed from the reactor fluid using equations above and just add this heat to the cooling fluid and see how the temperature increases.

thank you! How do I find $\overline{T}C$? Is it okay to assume that it equals $(T{cs}+T_{cf})/2$ and to also assume that $T_{cs}=10^{\circ}C$ and $T_{cf}=37^{\circ}C$? And is $t_f$ the total time to reach $37^{\circ}C$ in the reactor? How could I find $t_f$ by considering that $K$ is known (or alternatively how could I find $K$?)?

The mean cooling temperature is not mean in time but in space, i.e. along the cooling channel. If the cooling fluid flow rate is very high, this temperature would get close to the inlet temperature 10 °C. $t_f$ can be calculated using the 3th or 4th equation from the end, but I assume the cooling time is one of the input parameters, isn't it?

I assumed that the final temperature in the cooling jacket is $37^{\circ}C$ so that I can compute the driving force of the process $\Delta T_{\text{med}}$ and I obtained that the flow is about $3.8 \text{kg}/\text{s}$ (here I assumed that $K=1100 \text{W}/\text{m}^2\text{K}$ and I used the whole transfer area). I also computed the time and it is around $1400 \text{s}$.

Furthermore, shouldn't the final temperature be ideally larger (let's say $37^{\circ}C$ for example) and to have a smaller flow rate so that the costs are minimized?

I would expect you need to cool the reactor in a given time for which you would need to design parameters of the jacket. What do you mean by the final temperature in the jacket? Is it output temperature? I assume input cooling fluid temperature will be always 10 °C.

What type of jacket will you be using? Is it like a helical coil or a different design?

yes, the final termperature is the temperature at which the water exits the cooling jacket. Now what I would also like to know is how to compute the flow rate if the temperature both when the water enters and exits the jacket is $10^{\circ}C$. We would have $Q_{\text{given}}=1.05\cdot G_v\cdot C_p(T_{cf}-T_{cs})$ and the paranthesis and thus the result would be zero, right? Moreover, when I compute $Q_{\text{given}}$ is it fine to write $Q_{\text{given}}=1.05\cdot G_v \cdot C_p \cdot \Delta T_{\text{med}}$, where...

$\Delta T_{\text{med}}=\frac{(T_{rs}-\overline{T}c)-(T{rf}-\overline{T}c)}{\ln\left(\frac{T{rs}-\overline{T}c}{T{rf}-\overline{T}_c}\right)}$?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
